# Javascript foreach loop recursive function

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

In html i have the text input as [http://www.zfun.com/api/order/{companies->id}](http://www.zfun.com/api/order/%7Bcompanies-%3Eid%7D)

HTML:

```
<form
  class="forms-sample"
  id="requestform"
  name="requestform"
  enctype="multipart/form-data"
>
  <div id="getmethod">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input
        type="hidden"
        id="requesturl"
        name="requesturl"
        value="{{$getrequesturl}}"
      />

      <div class="input-group">Enter Store URL</div>
      <div class="input-group">
        <input
          type="text"
          id="storeurl"
          name="storeurl"
          class="urlconcat form-control marginleft"
          aria-label="Text input with dropdown button"
          placeholder="Enter Store Url"
          value="{{$getstoreurl}}"
        />
      </div>
      <br /><br />
      <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
          <select class="form-control" id="method" name="method">
            <option value='GET' @if($getmethodname == 'GET') selected="selected" @endif>GET</option>
            <option value='POST' @if($getmethodname == 'POST') selected="selected" @endif>POST</option>
            <option value='PUT' @if($getmethodname == 'PUT') selected="selected" @endif>PUT</option>
            <option value='DELETE' @if($getmethodname == 'DELETE') selected="selected" @endif>DELETE</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <input
          Ftype="text"
          id="endpoint"
          name="endpoint"
          class="urlconcat requesturltext getrequesturl form-control marginleft"
          aria-label="Text input with dropdown button"
          placeholder="Enter End Point"
          value="{{$getendpoint}}"
        />
        <button
          type="submit"
          class="btn btn-primary mr-2 marginleft"
          id="savebtn"
        >
          Send
        </button>
        <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button">Cancel</button>
        <button
          class="btn btn-success mr-2 marginleft"
          id="addurl"
          type="button"
        >
          + Add URL
        </button>
        <button
          class="removeurl btn btn-danger mr-2 marginleft"
          type="button"
          style="display: none"
        >
          Remove
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

i have array values in javascript as

```json
{
  "id": 245,
  "fullName": "ZFUser ",
  "type": "Partner",
  "token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1bmlxdWVfbmFtZSI6ImFjdXRyYWNrQHpvbmVmdW5uZWwuY29tIiwicm9sZSI6IlRoaXJkUGFydHlVc2VyIiwiQ29tcGFueSI6IkFCQyIsIlRva2VuVHlwZSI6IkxvZ2luIiwiVXNlcklkIjoiMjQ1IiwiQ29tcGFueVR5cGUiOiJQYXJ0bmVyIiwibmJmIjoxNjE3MjY5MDYxLCJleHAiOjE2MTcyNzI2NjAsImlhdCI6MTYxNzI2OTA2MX0.Y41hjF_iINZZeXN0_rAPs5Zv7B9cGhtjtTxe32fhTrQ",
  "refreshToken": "XRDNLL3vcAMgD4qGnVMav/O1YarZrZM9OKqWjLAi3Ao=",
  "role": "ThirdPartyUser",
  "weightUOM": "LB",
  "currencyUOM": "USD",
  "dimensionUOM": "IN",
  "companies": [
    {
      "id": 3,
      "company": "ABC",
      "role": "ThirdPartyUser",
      "gatewayId": 0,
      "storeName": null,
      "isDefault": true
    }
  ],
  "secureObjects": [
    {
      "category": "Order",
      "secureObjects": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "className": "ShippingInfo"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

If I click send button, i need to replace the value for {companies->id} with 3 which is in array.

I tried the code,

```
function getloop(ss,tagresult){
  $.each(tagresult, function (i,vall){ 
    var s="";//console.log(i);
    ss.forEach(function loop(index,item1) {
      if(loop.stop){ return; }
      if(i==index && (typeof vall[item1]=='object' || typeof vall[item1]=='array')){
         tagresult=vall[item1];alert(typeof vall[item1]);
         ss = jQuery.grep(ss, function(value) {
              return value != item1;
         });
         loop.stop = true;  
         getloop(ss,tagresult);     
       }
       if(i==index && typeof vall[item1]!='object' && typeof vall[item1]!='array'){
        s=vall.item1;alert(i+"---"+index);alert("s"+s);//console.log(s);//console.log(vall[0][item1]);
      }
    });
    }); 
}
```

tagresult is the array with values.

ss is the array which i achieved using companies->id.split("->");

So, ss has the values as ss=["companies","id"]

If the url is [http://www.zfun.com/api/order/{companies->id}/{companies->gatewayId},i](http://www.zfun.com/api/order/%7Bcompanies-%3Eid%7D/%7Bcompanies-%3EgatewayId%7D,i) need to replace gatewayid also.

My expected output is

```
http://www.zfun.com/api/order/3
http://www.zfun.com/api/order/3/0
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Provide the html please

Comment: @MathieuLescaudron, i have added my html code.in the endpoint i have to replace values in the url.

Comment: When you say that you need to replace the value in an array, how do you determine that the id 3 is correct? What is the metho behind `savebtn`?

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me that this can be solved by mapping the values in the array to the wanted URL structure rather than doing recursion:

```js
const tagresult = [
  {
    "id": 245,
    "fullName": "ZFUser ",
    "type": "Partner",
    "token": "eyJhbGciOiJCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1bmlxdWVfbmyYWNrQHpvbmVmdW5uZWwuY29tIiwicm9sZSI6IlRoaXJkUGFydHlVc2VyIiwiQ29tcGFueSI6IkFCQyIs6IkxvZ2luIiwiVXNlcklkIjoiMjQ1IiwiQ29tcGFueVR5cGUiOiJQYXJ0bmVyIiwibmJmIjoxNjE3MjY5MDYxLCJleHAiOmlhdCI6MTYxNzI2OTA2MX0.Y41hjF_iINZZeXN0_rAPs5Zv7B9cGhtjtTxe32fhTrQ",
    "refreshToken": "XRDNLL3vcAMgD4qGnVMav/O1YarZrZM9OKqWjLAi3Ao=",
    "role": "ThirdPartyUser",
    "weightUOM": "LB",
    "currencyUOM": "USD",
    "dimensionUOM": "IN",
    "companies": [
      {
        "id": 3,
        "company": "ABC",
        "role": "ThirdPartyUser",
        "gatewayId": 0,
        "storeName": null,
        "isDefault": true
      }
    ],
    "secureObjects": [
      {
        "category": "Order",
        "secureObjects": [
          {
            "id": 1,
            "className": "ShippingInfo"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]

const output = tagresult.flatMap(val => val.companies.flatMap(comp => [`http://www.zfun.com/api/order/${comp.id}`, `http://www.zfun.com/api/order/${comp.id}/${comp.gatewayId}`]));

console.log(output);
```

Comment: Btw, be careful with pasting JWT tokens in questions as they might contain sensitive data.

Comment: the companies key should not be static. it should be any key.also comp.id and comp.gatewayid should also be from the mapped url value {companies->id},{companies->gatewayid}